# Selectively show items in a dropdownlist

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have 2 drop down lists - ddlCompanies, and ddlContacts.

Lets say -

```
Companies | Company A | Company B | Company C |
----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
Contacts  | Albo      | Bill      | Charlie   |
          | Alex      | Bob       | Chad      |
          | Aaron     | Brad      | Dennis    |
```

in ddlCompanys i list - Company A, Company B and Company C
in ddlContacts, I load all the contacts, Alex, bob, chad, ...

Now in the user control, i would like to display only those names (in ddlContacts0 that belong to the selected company (ddlCompany)

EDIT: 
Code to load the dropdowns

```
ddlCompanies.DataSource = companies; //companies is instance of  IEnumerable<ListItem>
//Also the text of the list item is the name of the company, and value is the ID
ddlCompanies.DataTextField = "Text";
ddlCompanies.DataValueField = "Value";
ddlCompanies.DataBind();
```

Code for ddlcontacts

```
ddlContacts.DataSource = allContacts // all contacts is instance of IEnumerable<ListItem> and contains all the contacts for all companies.  
//The text Value Contains the name of the employee, and value is the ID
//If needed, I can look up the company for the contact in the code behind.
ddlContacts.DataTextField = "Text";
ddlContacts.DataValueField = "Value";
ddlContacts.DataBind();
```

Can some one help me with this-

Thanks,

Comment: I answered a question similar to this at the weekend, it might be of some help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7697936/jquery-show-hide-options-from-one-select-drop-down-when-option-on-other-select-d/7698054#7698054

Comment: What is the filtering criteria? When the company changes, do you need to fetch the contacts from the database, or do you have all contacts from all companies loaded, with some way to distinguish them?

Comment: @JamesJohnson I have the companies and contacts loaded on the page load.

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question. Are the contacts for *all* companies loaded in the contacts dropdown?

Comment: Please post the markup for the DropDownLists, and anything else that might be relevant. There are a lot of ways to do this.

Comment: @everyone: Updated the question to show how the values for the companies and contacts are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I would use ASP.NET to write some JavaScript (with `<%= %>` tags).

```
var contacts;
contacts['A'] = 'Albo,Alex,Aaron';
contacts['B'] = 'Bill,Bob,Brad';
contacts['C'] = 'Charlie,Chad,Dennis';
```

This information is extracted from the database and written to the page like that, within `<script>` tags, by ASP.NET.

Now you can use jQuery to make it so whenever `ddlCompanies` changes, a function is called which uses the selected value of `ddlCompanies` to decide which element of the `contacts` array to use. It then splits this string and puts all the items into `ddlContacts`.

I won't try to write the exact code here, because I'd probably make mistakes. Comment if you can't make it work for you. :)