# Select drop down list not displaying properly when list gets lengthy

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I am trying to achieve something like this:
[jQuery show/hide options from one select drop down, when option on other select dropdown is slected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7697936/jquery-show-hide-options-from-one-select-drop-down-when-option-on-other-select)

Here's what I've done and it's working fine, except when I click on Yearly or Quarterly, the Frequency list displays only one item and I have to click the scroll up/down button to see the other options.

HTML

```
<td> Consumption type :</td>
<td>
<select id="consumption" class="form-control" style = "width:400px"> 
<option value= "menu" selected> Select consumption type </option>
<option value="daily">Daily</option>
<option value="weekly">Weekly</option>
<option value="monthly">Monthly</option>
<option value="yearly">Yearly</option>
<option value="quarterly">Quarterly</option>
</select>
</td>


<td> Frequency : </td>
<td>
<select id="frequency" class="form-control" style = "width:400px" disabled> 
<option selected> Select frequency </option>

<!--Weekly Options-->
<option class="weekly" value="monday">Monday</option>
<option class="weekly" value="tuesday">Tuesday</option>
<option class="weekly" value="wednesday">Wednesday</option>
<option class="weekly" value="thursday">Thursday</option>
<option class="weekly" value="friday">Friday</option>
<option class="weekly" value="saturday">Saturday</option>
<option class="weekly" value="sunday">Sunday</option>

<!--Monthly Options-->
<option class="monthly" value="1">1</option>
<option class="monthly" value="2">2</option>
<option class="monthly" value="3">3</option>
<option class="monthly" value="4">4</option>
<option class="monthly" value="5">5</option>
<option class="monthly" value="6">6</option>
<option class="monthly" value="7">7</option>
<option class="monthly" value="8">8</option>
<option class="monthly" value="9">9</option>
<option class="monthly" value="10">10</option>
<option class="monthly" value="11">11</option>
<option class="monthly" value="12">12</option> 
<option class="monthly" value="13">13</option>
<option class="monthly" value="14">14</option>
<option class="monthly" value="15">15</option>
<option class="monthly" value="16">16</option>
<option class="monthly" value="17">17</option>
<option class="monthly" value="18">18</option>
<option class="monthly" value="19">19</option>
<option class="monthly" value="20">20</option>
<option class="monthly" value="21">21</option>
<option class="monthly" value="22">22</option>
<option class="monthly" value="23">23</option>
<option class="monthly" value="24">24</option> 
<option class="monthly" value="25">25</option>
<option class="monthly" value="26">26</option>
<option class="monthly" value="27">27</option>
<option class="monthly" value="28">28</option>
<option class="monthly" value="29">29</option>
<option class="monthly" value="30">30</option>
<option class="monthly" value="31">31</option>                                                                                       

<!--Yearly/Quarterly Options-->                               
<option class="yearly" value="january">January</option>
<option class="yearly" value="february">February</option>
<option class="yearly" value="march">March</option>
<option class="yearly" value="april">April</option>
<option class="yearly" value="may">May</option>
<option class="yearly" value="june">June</option>
<option class="yearly" value="july">July</option>
<option class="yearly" value="august">August</option>
<option class="yearly" value="september">September</option>
<option class="yearly" value="october">October</option>
<option class="yearly" value="november">November</option>
<option class="yearly" value="december">December</option>                                                  

</select>
</td>
```

Script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#consumption").change(function () {
    var value = $("#consumption").attr("value");
    $(".weekly, .monthly, .yearly").hide();
    switch(value) {         
        case "weekly":
            {                            
                $("#frequency").removeAttr("disabled");                            
                $(".weekly").show();
            }
            break;
        case "monthly":
            {                            
                $("#frequency").removeAttr("disabled");                            
                $(".monthly").show();
            }
            break;
        case "yearly":
            {                            
                $("#frequency").removeAttr("disabled");                                                      
                $(".yearly").show();
            }
            break;
        case "quarterly":
            {                            
                $("#frequency").removeAttr("disabled");                            
                $(".yearly").show();
            }
            break;          
    }

    });
});
```

If anybody could help it would be much appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: Here's the screenshot of the drop-down list.

[image: Drop-down list not displaying properly]

Comment: $("#consumption").attr("value") will not give you yearly monthly or quarterly.

Comment: I've tried giving an alert() message to every case and it worked fine. Can you suggest a proper way to do it? I'm still new to jQuery. @ShoaibChikate

Comment: @Nate try var value = $("#consumption").val();

Comment: Thank you @rajmohan, still stuck in my current issue.

Comment: hi I think disabled is the issue

Comment: The reason for this behaviour is in your select tag you have 50 option and your yearly options come at the bottom. So when you select yearly,first 38 options are hidden and above space will be occupy them hence your yearly options are not seen. Instead you can use 3 select tags for the same

Comment: I removed the disabled attribute but it's still the same. I've added a screenshot of the drop-down list. @DholakiyaAnkit

Comment: @Nate check the plnkr  link I have provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue in another way. Please check the link

http://plnkr.co/edit/fnJUoDXa7TMRdEjNpPf5?p=preview

Comment: Please explain the reason and how you solve this issue. You have put yearly options above which i too tried but then issue was coming for monthly options.

Comment: @ShoaibChikate I have created multiple Frequency select box with different class name month, year and week then displayed them according to the value selected in consumption type

Comment: I suggested him same to have 3 different select tag.But question is how we can resolve if there is one select tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the height attribute of Select HTML element and try to manipulate its height in your conditions like:

```
$('#frequency').height('200px');
```

OR

try to change the size of the combobox like:

```
$('#frequency').size = 10;
```

Comment: I did what you suggested but when I clicked on Yearly/Quarterly the select element's size increases and still the option menu that will drop is short that only 1 item is displayed and I have to scroll down/up to see the other options. @Ryan

Comment: Try to set the "line-height" or "size" attribute of element