# jQuery show/hide options from one select drop down doesn't work, when option on other drop down is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

As it is said in the title, I would like to display options in `dropdownlist2` when a given option in dropdownlsit1 is selected..

I tried several solutions, the last one is : 
[jQuery show/hide options from one select drop down, when option on other select dropdown is slected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7697936/jquery-show-hide-options-from-one-select-drop-down-when-option-on-other-select)
I tried to use, but with no success.

**Code [link](https://github.com/fnagel/jquery-ui/wiki/Selectmenu).**

Problems are :

- In `dropdownlist2` there are optgroup that I would like to show/hide too
- the first options show/hide well, but for the last ones, display bugs (see "6 column")
- doesn't work on IE

My JS code

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#layout_select').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $("#column_select").change(function () {
            var colSelected = $("#column_select option:selected").val();
            var colSelectedText = $("#id_divisions option:selected").text();
            if (colSelected != 0){
                $('#layout_select').removeAttr('disabled');  
                $("#layout_select")
                .find("option")
                .show()
                .not("option[value*='" + this.value + "']").hide();

                $("#layout_select")
                .find("optgroup")
                .hide();

                $("#layout_select")
                .find("optgroup[label='" + colSelectedText + "']")
                .show();

                $("#layout_select").val(
                $("#layout_select").find("option:visible:first").val());
            }  else  {
                $('#layout_select option[value="0"]').attr("selected",true);
                $('#layout_select').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            }
        }).change();
    });
```

You can see the complete version with html [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Maryyy/4Sbt5/).
(I did try with chrome)

Thanks a lot

***EDIT***

I finally found a solution, maybe it isn't the good one, but it works on chrome, firefox and IE

HTML :

```
<select name="column_select" id="column_select">
    <option value="0">-----------------------------------</option>
    <option value="col1">1 column</option>
    <option value="col2">2 column</option>
    <option value="col3">3 column</option>
    <option value="col4">4 column</option>
    <option value="col5">5 column</option>
    <option value="col6">6 column</option>
</select>

<select name="layout_select" id="layout_select">
    <option value="0">-----------------------------------</option>
    <!--Below shows when '1 column' is selected is hidden otherwise-->
    <optgroup label="1 column">
    <option value="col1">none</option>
    </optgroup>

    <!--Below shows when '2 column' is selected is hidden otherwise-->
     <optgroup label="2 column">
    <option value="col2_ms">layout 1</option> 
    <option value="col2_sm">layout 2</option>
    </optgroup>

    <!--Below shows when '3 column' is selected is hidden otherwise-->
    <optgroup label="3 column">
    <option value="col3_mss">layout 3</option>
    <option value="col3_ssm">layout 4</option>
    <option value="col3_sms">layout 5</option>
    <option value="col3_sms">layout 6</option>
    <option value="col3_sms">layout 7</option>
    <option value="col3_sms">layout 8</option>
    </optgroup>

    <optgroup label="4 column">
    <option value="col4_ms">layout 9</option> 
    <option value="col4_sm">layout 10</option>
    <option value="col4_sm">layout 11</option>
    <option value="col4_sm">layout 12</option>
    <option value="col4_sm">layout 11</option>
    <option value="col4_sm">layout 12</option>
    </optgroup>

    <optgroup label="5 column">
    <option value="col5">Test</option>
    <option value="col5">Test2</option>
    </optgroup>

    <optgroup label="6 column">
    <option value="col6_ms">layout 13</option> 
    <option value="col6_sm">layout 14</option>
    <option value="col6_sm">layout 15</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>

<select id="backup" style="display:none;"></select>
```

JS :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#layout_select').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

    $.each($('#layout_select optgroup'),function( index, value ){
        $('#backup').append(value);  
    });   

    $("#column_select").change(function () {
        $('#layout_select optgroup').remove();
        $('#layout_select option').not("option[value='0']").remove();
        var colSelected = $("#column_select option:selected").val();
        var colSelectedText = $("#column_select option:selected").text();
        if (colSelected != 0){
            $('#layout_select').removeAttr('disabled');  
            $("#backup optgroup[label*='" + colSelectedText + "']").clone().appendTo("#layout_select");                           
            $("#layout_select").val(
            $("#layout_select").find("option:visible:first").val());
        }  else  {
            $('#layout_select option[value="0"]').attr("selected",true);
            $('#layout_select').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }            
    }).change();
});
```

Do not hesitate if you have any other suggestion.

Comment: See code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Maryyy/3vsXG/)

Answer (score 0):

i am able to go inside the if condition (if (colSelected != 0){) but somehow datagroup is not coming in the below data.

$( document ).ready(function() {

```
$.each($('#id_component_class optgroup'),function( index, value ){
    $('#backup').append(value);
});

$("#id_env_component").change(function () {
    $('#id_component_class optgroup').remove();
    $('#id_component_class option').not("option[value='0']").remove();
    var colSelected = $("#id_env_component option:selected").val();
    var colSelectedText = $("#id_env_component option:selected").text();
    alert(colSelectedText);
    if (colSelected != 0){
        alert("inside");
        $('#id_component_class').removeAttr('disabled');

        $("#backup optgroup[label*='" + colSelectedText + "']").clone().appendTo("#id_component_class");

        $("#id_component_class").val(
        $("#id_component_class").find("option:visible:first").val());
    }  else  {
        $('#id_component_class option[value="0"]').attr("selected",true);
        $('#id_component_class').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
}).change();
```

});

---

Comment: is this supposed to be an answer?