# Inter Dependent Dropdown List

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I know how to create dropdown Lists, but what I want is Inter Dependent Dropdown List..
Say List1 is of Country name, List2 is City...
At First, what  I want is List of all Countries as well all cities by default,then After selecting India, I must get Mumbai,Banglore in Second List.
But what I want is after selecting Mumbai, my list1 should change to India.
Any suggestions appreciated .
but remember, I know dependent dropdown,I Need Inter Dependent Dropdown.

Comment: You'll need to limit the number of options in one list depending upon the selected option in another. There was already an answer about it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery show/hide options from one select drop down, when option on other select dropdown is slected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7697936/jquery-show-hide-options-from-one-select-drop-down-when-option-on-other-select)