# jquery Show id option only if selected {help}

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to show only subcategorie of selected categorie by ID.
I tried with separated `select`, but with the same name is a long way because it needs to check every name for empty...
Maybe im wrong... I need some idea about this.

This is my HTML:

```
        <select class="form-control" name="catname" id="catname">
            <option value="">Zgjidh Kategorine</option>
            <option value="AUTOMJETE">AUTOMJETE</option>
            <option value="VENDBANIME">VENDBANIME</option>
            <option value="ELEKTRONIK">ELEKTRONIK</option>
            <option value="SPORT">SPORT</option>
            <option value="BIZNES-DHE-PUNE">BIZNES DHE PUNE</option>
            <option value="TE-TJERA">TE TJERA</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4" id="AUTOMJETE">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Zgjidh Nen-Kategorine</label>
        <select name="subname" class="form-control">
            <option value="">Zgjidh Nen-Kategorine</option>
            <option id="AUTOMJETE" value="Makina">Makina</option>
            <option id="AUTOMJETE" value="Pjese Kembimi">Pjese Kembimi</option>
            <option id="AUTOMJETE" value="Motocikleta">Motocikleta</option>
            <option id="AUTOMJETE" value="Makineri Tonazh i Rende">Makineri Tonazh i Rende</option>
            <option id="AUTOMJETE" value="Per Kamping">Per Kamping</option>
            <option id="AUTOMJETE" value="Per Bujqesi">Per Bujqesi</option>
            <option id="AUTOMJETE" value="Makineri Per Uje">Makineri Per Uje</option>
            <option id="VENDBANIME" value="Shtepi">Shtepi</option>
            <option id="VENDBANIME" value="Garazhde">Garazhde</option>
            <option id="VENDBANIME" value="Apartamente">Apartamente</option>
            <option id="VENDBANIME" value="Dhoma">Dhoma</option>
            <option id="VENDBANIME" value="Vila">Vila</option>
            <option id="VENDBANIME" value="Toke">Toke</option>
            <option id="VENDBANIME" value="Objekte">Objekte</option>
            <option id="ELEKTRONIK" value="Celulare">Celulare</option>
            <option id="ELEKTRONIK" value="Pjese Per Celulare">Pjese Per Celulare</option>
            <option id="ELEKTRONIK" value="Servis Celularesh">Servis Celularesh</option>
            <option id="ELEKTRONIK" value="Telefona Fiks">Telefona Fiks</option>
            <option id="ELEKTRONIK" value="Kompjutere">Kompjutere</option>
            <option id="ELEKTRONIK" value="Pjese Per Kompjuter">Pjese Per Kompjuter</option>
            <option id="ELEKTRONIK" value="Paisje Audio">Paisje Audio</option>
            <option id="ELEKTRONIK" value="Televizore">Televizore</option>
            <option id="ELEKTRONIK" value="Pjese Per Televizore">Pjese Per Televizore</option>
            <option id="ELEKTRONIK" value="Film / Muzike">Film / Muzike</option>
            <option id="ELEKTRONIK" value="Konzolate Per Lojra">Konzolate Per Lojra</option>
            <option id="SPORT" value="Paisje Sportive">Paisje Sportive</option>
            <option id="SPORT" value="Instrumente">Instrumente</option>
            <option id="SPORT" value="Veshje/Kepuce">Veshje/Kepuce</option>
            <option id="SPORT" value="Aksesore/Ora">Aksesore/Ora</option>
            <option id="SPORT" value="Libra/Revista">Libra/Revista</option>
            <option id="SPORT" value="Artikuj/Koleksion">Artikuj/Koleksion</option>
            <option id="SPORT" value="Turizem dhe Evente">Turizem dhe Evente</option>
            <option id="BIZNES-DHE-PUNE" value="Ambjente Biznesi">Ambjente Biznesi</option>
            <option id="BIZNES-DHE-PUNE" value="Dorezim Biznesi">Dorezim Biznesi</option>
            <option id="BIZNES-DHE-PUNE" value="Makineri Dhe Inventare">Makineri Dhe Inventare</option>
            <option id="BIZNES-DHE-PUNE" value="Shitje me Shumice">Shitje me Shumice</option>
            <option id="BIZNES-DHE-PUNE" value="Kafshe ne Ferme">Kafshe ne Ferme</option>
            <option id="BIZNES-DHE-PUNE" value="Sherbime">Sherbime</option>
            <option id="BIZNES-DHE-PUNE" value="Pune">Pune</option>
            <option id="TE-TJERA" value="TE NDRYSHME">TE NDRYSHME</option>
        </select>
```

And this is my jQuery code:

```
$(function() {
    $('#catname').change(function(){
        $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You have tons of duplicate IDs which invalid!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir any idea how to solve?

Comment: How did you get that HTML? Did you generated it using PHP? Or did you write it yourself?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir i writed it testing...

Comment: You'ld better change the ID attribute to class. `<option class="AUTOMJETE" val...` on all the option with duplicate IDs!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Thanks , founded the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7697936/jquery-show-hide-options-from-one-select-drop-down-when-option-on-other-select //

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use class instead of repeated ids.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#catname').change(function(){
      $('.col-md-4 option').hide();
      $('.' + $(this).val()).show();
   });
});
```

```css
.col-md-4 option{display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>

<select class="form-control" name="catname" id="catname">
        <option value="">Zgjidh Kategorine</option>
        <option value="AUTOMJETE">AUTOMJETE</option>
        <option value="VENDBANIME">VENDBANIME</option>
        <option value="ELEKTRONIK">ELEKTRONIK</option>
        <option value="SPORT">SPORT</option>
        <option value="BIZNES-DHE-PUNE">BIZNES DHE PUNE</option>
        <option value="TE-TJERA">TE TJERA</option>
    </select>

    <div class="col-md-4" id="AUTOMJETE">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Zgjidh Nen-Kategorine</label>
            <select name="subname" class="form-control">
            <option value="">Zgjidh Nen-Kategorine</option>
            <option class="AUTOMJETE" value="Makina">Makina</option>
            <option class="AUTOMJETE" value="Pjese Kembimi">Pjese Kembimi</option>
            <option class="AUTOMJETE" value="Motocikleta">Motocikleta</option>
            <option class="AUTOMJETE" value="Makineri Tonazh i Rende">Makineri Tonazh i Rende</option>
            <option class="AUTOMJETE" value="Per Kamping">Per Kamping</option>
            <option class="AUTOMJETE" value="Per Bujqesi">Per Bujqesi</option>
            <option class="AUTOMJETE" value="Makineri Per Uje">Makineri Per Uje</option>
            <option class="VENDBANIME" value="Shtepi">Shtepi</option>
            <option class="VENDBANIME" value="Garazhde">Garazhde</option>
            <option class="VENDBANIME" value="Apartamente">Apartamente</option>
            <option class="VENDBANIME" value="Dhoma">Dhoma</option>
            <option class="VENDBANIME" value="Vila">Vila</option>
            <option class="VENDBANIME" value="Toke">Toke</option>
            <option class="VENDBANIME" value="Objekte">Objekte</option>
            <option class="ELEKTRONIK" value="Celulare">Celulare</option>
            <option class="ELEKTRONIK" value="Pjese Per Celulare">Pjese Per Celulare</option>
            <option class="ELEKTRONIK" value="Servis Celularesh">Servis Celularesh</option>
            <option class="ELEKTRONIK" value="Telefona Fiks">Telefona Fiks</option>
            <option class="ELEKTRONIK" value="Kompjutere">Kompjutere</option>
            <option class="ELEKTRONIK" value="Pjese Per Kompjuter">Pjese Per Kompjuter</option>
            <option class="ELEKTRONIK" value="Paisje Audio">Paisje Audio</option>
            <option class="ELEKTRONIK" value="Televizore">Televizore</option>
            <option class="ELEKTRONIK" value="Pjese Per Televizore">Pjese Per Televizore</option>
            <option class="ELEKTRONIK" value="Film / Muzike">Film / Muzike</option>
            <option class="ELEKTRONIK" value="Konzolate Per Lojra">Konzolate Per Lojra</option>
            <option class="SPORT" value="Paisje Sportive">Paisje Sportive</option>
            <option class="SPORT" value="Instrumente">Instrumente</option>
            <option class="SPORT" value="Veshje/Kepuce">Veshje/Kepuce</option>
            <option class="SPORT" value="Aksesore/Ora">Aksesore/Ora</option>
            <option class="SPORT" value="Libra/Revista">Libra/Revista</option>
            <option class="SPORT" value="Artikuj/Koleksion">Artikuj/Koleksion</option>
            <option class="SPORT" value="Turizem dhe Evente">Turizem dhe Evente</option>
            <option class="BIZNES-DHE-PUNE" value="Ambjente Biznesi">Ambjente Biznesi</option>
            <option class="BIZNES-DHE-PUNE" value="Dorezim Biznesi">Dorezim Biznesi</option>
            <option class="BIZNES-DHE-PUNE" value="Makineri Dhe Inventare">Makineri Dhe Inventare</option>
            <option class="BIZNES-DHE-PUNE" value="Shitje me Shumice">Shitje me Shumice</option>
            <option class="BIZNES-DHE-PUNE" value="Kafshe ne Ferme">Kafshe ne Ferme</option>
            <option class="BIZNES-DHE-PUNE" value="Sherbime">Sherbime</option>
            <option class="BIZNES-DHE-PUNE" value="Pune">Pune</option>
            <option class="TE-TJERA" value="TE NDRYSHME">TE NDRYSHME</option>
        </select> 
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To begin with you must not use same id twice. You should use **class** or **data-*{something}*** attributes instead.

You should also use **for** attribute with your labels so that they are assigned to the control they label. And you should not label dropdown with a bogus entry, there is `<optgroup>` tag for that.

By the way, using $(this).val() makes no big sense as this.value is simpler and vanilla.

```
<select class="form-control" name="catname" id="catname">
    <optgroup label="Zgjidh Kategorine">
        <option value="AUTOMJETE">AUTOMJETE</option>
        <option value="VENDBANIME">VENDBANIME</option>
        <!-- etc. etc. -->
    </optgroup>
</select>
(…)
<label for="subname">Zgjidh Nen-Kategorine</label>
<select name="subname" id="subname" class="form-control">
    <optgroup label="Zgjidh Nen-Kategorine">
        <option class="AUTOMJETE" value="Makina">Makina</option>
        <option class="AUTOMJETE" value="Pjese Kembimi">Pjese Kembimi</option>
        <option class="AUTOMJETE" value="Motocikleta">Motocikleta</option>
        <option class="VENDBANIME" value="Shtepi">Shtepi</option>
        <option class="VENDBANIME" value="Garazhde">Garazhde</option>
        <option class="VENDBANIME" value="Apartamente">Apartamente</option>
        <!-- etc. etc. -->
    </optgroup>
</select>
<script>
    $('#catname').change(function(){
        $('#subname option').hide();
        $('#subname .' + this.value).show();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Jakub. you are Great!