# Select2 hide options with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, jquery-select2

I need to show/hide options on one select drop down dependant on another select drop down option.

My code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#layout_select").select2();
   $("#column_select").select2();

   $("#layout_select").children('option:gt(0)').hide();
   $("#column_select").change(function() {
      $("#layout_select").children('option').hide();
      $("#layout_select").children("option[value^=" + $(this).val() + "]").show()
   })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.12/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.12/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<select name="column_select" id="column_select">
   <option value="col1">1 column</option>
   <option value="col2">2 column</option>
   <option value="col3">3 column</option>
</select>

<select name="layout_select" id="layout_select">
  <option value="col1">none</option>

  <option value="col2_ms">layout 1</option> 
  <option value="col2_sm">layout 2</option>

  <option value="col3_mss">layout 3</option>
  <option value="col3_ssm">layout 4</option>
  <option value="col3_sms">layout 5</option>
 </select>
```

When I change the selection of my first 'column_select', I want to change my 'layout_select' options using hide / show

Something like [this StackOverflow issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7697936/jquery-show-hide-options-from-one-select-drop-down-when-option-on-other-select)

**Note: I am using Select2.**

In my implementation I did exactly as the example, but as I am using select2 scrpit does not work.

Does anyone know how to do the same thing, knowing that I'm using **select2**?  Without using .remove () and .append (), but exactly as in the example giving hide / show.

Comment: Have you tried calling `$("#layout_select").select2();` again after hidding its options ?

Comment: No unfortunately nothing is working even the `$("#layout_select").children('option').hide(); `. 
How to calling again?

Comment: Maybe you could check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26978884/2168947) and add a disabled attribute instead of hidding your options.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26978884/2168947), you could **disable** the options instead of hiding them and use CSS to hide the options if you want (they will be grayed out otherwise).

You will have to call `$("#layout_select").select2();` at the end of the `change` event and call `$("#column_select").change();` to trigger the change event on page load.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#layout_select").select2();
   $("#column_select").select2();

   $("#layout_select").children('option:gt(0)').hide();
   $("#column_select").change(function() {
      $("#layout_select").children('option').prop('disabled', true);
      $("#layout_select").children("option[value^=" + $(this).val() + "]").prop('disabled', false);
      $("#layout_select").select2();
   })
   $("#column_select").change();
});
```

```css
.select2-container--default .select2-results__option[aria-disabled=true] {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.12/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.12/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<select name="column_select" id="column_select">
   <option value="col1">1 column</option>
   <option value="col2">2 column</option>
   <option value="col3">3 column</option>
</select>

<select name="layout_select" id="layout_select">
  <option value="col1">none</option>

  <option value="col2_ms">layout 1</option> 
  <option value="col2_sm">layout 2</option>

  <option value="col3_mss">layout 3</option>
  <option value="col3_ssm">layout 4</option>
  <option value="col3_sms">layout 5</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that solved my problem. Saved my day.

Comment: @mik_assad You can [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) this answer then ;)