# hiding options of select by id in jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, drop-down-menu

I wanna hide or show my options in a select when a options in another select being choose.
I find this jquery for my problem
[jQuery show/hide options from one select drop down, when option on other select dropdown is slected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7697936/jquery-show-hide-options-from-one-select-drop-down-when-option-on-other-select/38014840)

but I want to it works by option id instead  option value.
I changed this jquery like below for my project but it doesn't work like when it works with value.
what should I do?

```
<div>       
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#secq").children('option:gt(0)').hide();
    $("#q").change(function() {
        $("#secq").children('option').hide();
        $("#secq").children("option[id^=" + $(this).id + "]").show()
    })
})


</script>

<form action="/Search" class="search-form" method="get">
    <fieldset>
        <select id="q" name="q" required><option value="">یک گزینه را انتخاب کنید</option>
            <option id="1" value="ویزای کشورهای قاره آمریکا"> ویزای کشورهای قاره آمریکا </option>
            <option id="2" value="ویزای کشورهای قاره اروپا"> ویزای کشورهای قاره اروپا </option>
            <option id="3" value="ویزا کشورهای همسایه"> ویزای کشورهای همسایه </option>
            <option id="4" value="ویزای کشورهای آسیا"> ویزای کشورهای آسیا </option>
            <option id="5" value="ویزای کشورهای آفریقا"> ویزای کشورهای آفریقا </option>
            <option id="6" value="ویزای کشورهای قاره اقیانوسیه"> ویزای کشورهای قاره اقیانوسیه </option>
        </select>

        <select id="secq" name="secq" required><option value="">یک گزینه را انتخاب کنید</option>
            <option id="1_1" value="ویزا توریستی کانادا"  >ویزای توریستی کانادا</option>
            <option id="1_2" value="ویزا تحصیلی کانادا"  >ویزای تحصیلی کانادا</option>
            <option id="1_3" value="ویزا دیدار از خانواده کانادا"  >ویزای دیدار از خانواده کانادا</option>
            <option id="1_4" value="ویزا توریستی آمریکا"  >ویزای توریستی آمریکا</option>
            <option id="1_5" value="ویزا تحصیلی آمریکا"  >ویزای تحصیلی آمریکا</option>
            <option id="1_6" value="ویزا دیدار از خانواده آمریکا"  >ویزای دیدار از خانواده آمریکا</option>
            <option id="1_7" value="ویزا مکزیک"  >ویزای مکزیک</option>
            <option id="1_8" value="ویزا کوبا"  >ویزای کوبا</option>
            <option id="1_9" value="ویزا برزیل"  >ویزای برزیل</option>
            <option id="2_1" value="ویزا شنگن کوتاه مدت">ویزای شنگن کوتاه مدت</option>
            <option id="2_2" value="ویزا شنگن بلند مدت">ویزای شنگن بلند مدت</option>
            <option id="2_3" value="ویزا اوکراین">ویزای اوکراین</option>
            <option id="2_4" value="ویزا بلغارستان">ویزای بلغارستان</option>
            <option id="2_5" value="ویزا کرواسی">ویزای کرواسی</option>
            <option id="2_6" value="ویزا شنگن از ایتالیا">ویزای شنگن از ایتالیا</option>
            <option id="2_7" value="ویزا شنگن از فرانسه">ویزای شنگن از فرانسه</option>
            <option id="2_8" value="ویزا شنگن از اسپاینا">ویزای شنگن از اسپاینا</option>
            <option id="2_9" value="ویزا شنگن از سوئیس">ویزا شنگن از سوئیس</option>
            <option id="2_10" value="ویزا شنگن از آلمان">ویزا شنگن از آلمان</option>
            <option id="2_11" value="ویزا شنگن از هلند">ویزا شنگن از هلند</option>
            <option id="2_12" value="ویزا شنگن از سوئد">ویزا شنگن از سوئد</option>
      </select>




        <input id="culture" name="culture" type="hidden" value="fa-IR">
        <button type="submit">جستجو</button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
    </div>
```

thanks for ur help;)

Comment: Please note that you html is incorrect. You haven't closed the values correctly, you are doing `value=" <"` but it should be `value="">`

Comment: your select `option[id^=" + $(this).id + "]"` translates to *select all option tags with an id **that starts with** (^) the value of this select*. But **all** your ids of your second select start with `1` so you will only select all options if you select 1 or none if you select something else. Use `$` instead of `^` to select all options that end with the value

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I did it like the query in the link and that's not the problem.

Comment: @Lapskaus the ids are samples. I'm gonna add ids like 2_1 and 3_1 later. Now, I want to try it then complete code.  but can you explain more about the problem of ```^``` and using ```$```. I didn't understand it.

Comment: @mohammad97mha It might now be the problem but you should always aim to have correct html in your code, because it might be the root of some problems, also your `id="3` is missing the end `"`

Comment: tanks for `id="3`i fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#secq").children('option:gt(0)').hide();
  $("#q").change(function() {
    $("#secq").children('option').hide();
    $("#secq").children("option[id^=" + $("option:selected",this).attr("id") + "]").show()
  })
})
```

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#secq").children('option:gt(0)').hide();
  $("#q").change(function() {
    $("#secq").children('option').hide();
    $("#secq").children("option[id^=" + $("option:selected",this).attr("id") + "]").show()
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="/Search" class="search-form" method="get">
  <fieldset>
    <select id="q" name="q" required>
      <option value="">یک گزینه را انتخاب کنید</option>
      <option id="1" value="ویزای کشورهای قاره آمریکا"> ویزای کشورهای قاره آمریکا </option>
      <option id="2" value="ویزای کشورهای قاره اروپا"> ویزای کشورهای قاره اروپا </option>
      <option id="3" value="ویزا کشورهای همسایه"> ویزای کشورهای همسایه </option>
      <option id="4" value="ویزای کشورهای آسیا"> ویزای کشورهای آسیا </option>
      <option id="5" value="ویزای کشورهای آفریقا"> ویزای کشورهای آفریقا </option>
      <option id="6" value="ویزای کشورهای قاره اقیانوسیه"> ویزای کشورهای قاره اقیانوسیه </option>
    </select>

    <select id="secq" name="secq" required>
      <option value="">یک گزینه را انتخاب کنید</option>
      <option id="1_1" value="ویزا توریستی کانادا">ویزای توریستی کانادا</option>
      <option id="1_2" value="ویزا تحصیلی کانادا">ویزای تحصیلی کانادا</option>
      <option id="1_3" value="ویزا دیدار از خانواده کانادا">ویزای دیدار از خانواده کانادا</option>
      <option id="1_4" value="ویزا توریستی آمریکا">ویزای توریستی آمریکا</option>
      <option id="1_5" value="ویزا تحصیلی آمریکا">ویزای تحصیلی آمریکا</option>
      <option id="1_6" value="ویزا دیدار از خانواده آمریکا">ویزای دیدار از خانواده آمریکا</option>
      <option id="1_7" value="ویزا مکزیک">ویزای مکزیک</option>
      <option id="1_8" value="ویزا کوبا">ویزای کوبا</option>
      <option id="1_9" value="ویزا برزیل">ویزای برزیل</option>
      <option id="2_1" value="ویزا شنگن کوتاه مدت">ویزای شنگن کوتاه مدت</option>
      <option id="2_2" value="ویزا شنگن بلند مدت">ویزای شنگن بلند مدت</option>
      <option id="2_3" value="ویزا اوکراین">ویزای اوکراین</option>
      <option id="2_4" value="ویزا بلغارستان">ویزای بلغارستان</option>
      <option id="2_5" value="ویزا کرواسی">ویزای کرواسی</option>
      <option id="2_6" value="ویزا شنگن از ایتالیا">ویزای شنگن از ایتالیا</option>
      <option id="2_7" value="ویزا شنگن از فرانسه">ویزای شنگن از فرانسه</option>
      <option id="2_8" value="ویزا شنگن از اسپاینا">ویزای شنگن از اسپاینا</option>
      <option id="2_9" value="ویزا شنگن از سوئیس">ویزا شنگن از سوئیس</option>
      <option id="2_10" value="ویزا شنگن از آلمان">ویزا شنگن از آلمان</option>
      <option id="2_11" value="ویزا شنگن از هلند">ویزا شنگن از هلند</option>
      <option id="2_12" value="ویزا شنگن از سوئد">ویزا شنگن از سوئد</option>
    </select>




    <input id="culture" name="culture" type="hidden" value="fa-IR">
    <button type="submit">جستجو</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```